# NodeJS: Promise or Fork for time consuming (2-5 mins) functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, fork

I have come across a use case in nodejs where one of the async function  completes within 2-5 mins. This function has some awaited async functions inside it. The code looks like:

```
async mainFunc(param1, param2, param3){
    await func1(param1);    //some DB activity
    await func2(param2);    //some SSH acitivity
    await func3(param3);    //some API calls
    ......
    ......
    // removed "return someResult;"
    notify(result);
}
```

`mainFunc` is triggerred by a REST API and it takes minutes to finish. The REST API doesn't wait for its completion though, so something like this (in express)

```
app.post('/run', (req, res)=>{
    const { param1, param2, param3 } = req.body;
    mainFunc(param1, param2, param3);
    return res.status(200).send('Initiated');
})
```

Assuming that I will be getting multiple client requests on `/run`. My question is- should I be using `mainFunc` as a promise or should I be forking a child process which runs `mainFunc`. I am not able to decide which approach would be better given mainFunc can take upto 10 mins to finish. Please help me understand pros and cons of both the approaches - Promise and Fork.

Comment: What you really should be doing is not having routes that take 2-5 minutes to complete. Instead, follow the REST pattern and make that route _initiate_ whatever needs to happen and then respond with a 200 and some content that signals the action is in progress, so that the client can occasionally ask for the result by calling the same URL, until the response is 200 with the result payload instead of "in progress". And then you need to figure out why it takes so incredibly long to do the work you need done: 2-5 minutes for a db query is absolutely crazy, and suggests your SQL needs work.

Comment: Assuming all the calls in `mainFunc` are properly asynchronous and not cpu-heavy, there's no reason to fork a child process for them.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Most of the time goes in running script on a remote server (using SSH).

Comment: That's even stragner: what does it do? With that said, that just makes the the original point even more important: don't even make _your own_ connection wait in this case. `await` the fast db call, then fire off that SSH call and if _it_ doesn't respond with "I finished the work for these arguments, the result is: ..." close the request with a "pending" response. Whatever the the ssh call does, already happens independently of your own code.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans "don't even make your own connection wait in this case" -  which connection?
"close the request with a "pending" response" - request is already not waiting on ```mainFunction```. What am I misunderstanding in your comment?

Comment: Sorry, missed the part where you're not `await`ing mainFunc, I saw it have a `return` statement, which it shouldn't have if you don't do anything with that data.  Having said that, if `func2` takes a long time to complete, it's really kind of important to understand what this code is _actually_ doing. `await` is designed to not block the JS engine, so as long as you're not keeping the request open, this code is already basically fine.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans agree with ```return``` thing. Updated the sample code. "```await``` is designed to not block the JS engine" - thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Just a  follow up question - How do I cancel an ongoing ```mainFunc```. As far I know promises can't be cancelled whereas forked processes can be terminated from parent process. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Yeah: you can't cancel them because there's no safe way to do so. If your tasks should be cancellable, you'll have to write code to safely achieve that; using a fork doesn't make that any safer, it just lets you _force kill_ a process, rather than cleanly have it exit. Update whatever code should be interruptible so that you can tell it to stop doing what it's doing and then cleanly exit or return (if necessary).

Comment: Agreed. Fork with graceful exit could do but..... not a very convinving way though.